# Join dots in scatter plot with lines throws an error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I've been following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130227/matplotlib-connect-scatterplot-points-with-line-python) in order to connect points in a scatter plot with lines, the written code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#data exploration
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv",encoding = 'utf8')
scan=[range(1,55)]
row2=data.iloc[1,1:]
plt.scatter(scan,row2)
#plt.plot(scan,row2)
```

If I remove the last line comment then terminal throws out:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1, 54) and (54,)
```

And prints only the scatterplot. Any help with this? I don't know how to build a complete MWE in this case (sorry for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting your `range` object to a list as

```
scan = list(range(1,55))
plt.scatter(scan, row2)
plt.plot(scan, row2)
```

Comment: perfect. Can you please describe briefly why it doesn't work? You don't have to, anyways. I don't understand why [ ] is different from list( )