# Matplotlib connect scatterplot points with line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I read the question  [Matplotlib connect scatterplot points with line - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130227/matplotlib-connect-scatterplot-points-with-line-python) but it doesn't work for me...

I tried to use `plt.scatter(x, y)` and after that `plt.show()`, but all that I see is a set of separated dots from each other.

[image: Like that:]

I think, that problem consists in that I use a loop for generating each point on the plot and after that loop, I use `plt.show()`.

All my code looks like this:

```
x = 0
y = 0
def eye_gaze1(a,b):
    global x,y
    image_plot1 = plt.imshow(image1)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if stimulus_name[x+y+1] == '5_01.jpg' and a[x+y+1] != '-':
            plt.scatter([a[x+y+1]], [b[x+y+1]]) #here I putting new point on the image_plot1 and this process repeats (something like 1000 times) before in my massive of data cycle will find '-' symbol
            x += 1
        else:
            x += 1
            break

    plt.show() #final image
    y += x
    x = 0

j = 0    
while j < 15: #just repeat this function for another cells in data-massive 
    eye_gaze1(col_values_X_right,col_values_Y_right) 
    j += 1
```

So, question is, how can I connect points?

---

If I try to use the comment of JohanC, I see this error: `TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

```
x = 0
y = 0
def eye_gaze1(a,b):
    global x,y
    image_plot1 = plt.imshow(image1)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if stimulus_name[x+y+1] == '5_01.jpg' and a[x+y+1] != '-':
            X_coordinates = list().append(a[x+y+1])
            Y_coordinates = list().append(b[x+y+1])

            x += 1
        else:
            x += 1
            break
    plt.scatter(X_coordinates, Y_coordinates, '-o')    
    plt.show()
    y += x
    x = 0

j = 0    
while j < 15:
    eye_gaze1(col_values_X_right,col_values_Y_right)
    print(x)
    print(y)
    j += 1
```

Comment: Instead of calling `plt.scatter` inside your `for` loop, you could gather all the x and all the y values into new arrays (e.g. `xvals` and `yvals`). After the loop, you can call `plt.plot(xvals, yvals, ...)`.

Comment: @JohanC If try to do it, I see this error `TypeError: ufunc 'sqrt' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: @JohanC Or if I delete ``-o`` parameter --- no dots on the images

Comment: Well, you should set `X_coordinates = []` before the `for`loop and call `X_coordinates.append(a[x+y+1])` inside the loop.

Comment: @JohanC Yeah, it works, thank you