# Generate random points and generating a path for it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate 10 different points on an x,y scatterplot and there would be a path that could go through every point and return to the starting point.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_points = 10
x1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
x2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
y1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
y2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
xy1 = [x1,y1]

plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='blue')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='red')
plt.show()
```

result: [scatterplot of 10 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EL42.png)

goal: [this was done via paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD5t5.png)

Comment: what are the constraints?  No constraints --> spaghetti lines. No crossed lines --> you can use simple algorithms based on angles. Shortest path --> that's NP-hard and is called the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
plt.plot(x1,y1)
```

This solution was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130227/matplotlib-connect-scatterplot-points-with-line-python) thread, and I will try on my machine momentarily.

edit: this doesn't connect the endpoints. do this instead:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_points = 10
x1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
x2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
y1 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
y2 = [random.randrange(start=1, stop=10) for i in range(num_points)]
xy1 = [x1,y1]


plt.scatter(x1, y1, c='blue')
plt.scatter(x2, y2, c='red')
plt.plot(x1,y1,c='blue')
plt.plot([x1[0],x1[-1]],[y1[0],y1[-1]],c='blue') #connects first and last point
plt.plot(x2,y2,c='red')
plt.plot([x2[0],x2[-1]],[y2[0],y2[-1]],c='red') #connects first and last point in second set

plt.show()
```